# Sorting a table in the front-end

Tags: add-on-development, table

I'm using the Table class to render a table in my module and I want the user to be able to sort by clicking on column headers. I'm following the docs [here](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/table.html), but when I use `set_columns` and `set_data` I get an error from `libraries/EE_Table.php` stating that `EE::$cp` is not defined.

Is it not possible to do sortable tables in the front-end? From the error, I guess it is only possible in the control panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EE uses the codeigniter table library .. 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/cp_styles/index.html#table-based-layout

The issue you're probably running into is that it's trying to use one of the default CP styles.  The library itself should be usable without being in the control panel, though jquery tablesorter may still be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've managed to use the library to create tables without any problem, as it's easier to pass it arrays than to create HTML tables manually myself and I will look into using tablesorter for sorting.